# When to use post increment and pre increment in Java

Tags: java, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

I understand that there are a number of questions on this topic on StackOverflow. But I am still slightly confused and unsure of when to use the operations. I am going through old tests in studying for my exam. One of the methods returns the number of classrooms that are handicapped accessible and are available. I wrote the counter method but am not sure if I am supposed to pre-increment or post increment the counter. I am confused as to how it works with return statement in methods. I still do not get what value the method will return below. The other questions do not show return values in methods and thus I am confused as to practically how it works. Here is the code:

```
  public int howManyHandi()
{
    int counter= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _clsrms.length; i++){
        if (_clsrms[i].handicappedSuitable() && _clsrms[i].isAvailable()){
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PRE-increment is used when you want to use the incremented value of the variable in that expression., whereas POST-increment uses the original value before incrementing it.

Whenever your code encounters a PRE-increment, it increments the value of that variable in the memory, then load that value and continues reading the expression.

POST-increment does the opposite, it loads that value of that variable in the memory, then increments the value and continues reading the expression.

To make it more clear, consider this

```
int i = counter++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i = counter;
counter = counter + 1;
```

WHEREAS

```
int i = ++counter;
```

is equivalent to

```
counter = counter + 1;
int i = counter;
```

EDIT: My StackOverflow comments arent working, so I'll just edit it here.

What I'm saying it, it only matters when you use that value in an expression.

```
sum = 0
counter = 0;
sum = (++counter)+(++counter)+(counter++)
```

evaluates as

```
sum = 0
counter = 0
//For first ++counter
counter = counter + 1
sum = counter

//For second ++counter
counter = counter + 1
sum = sum + counter

//For first counter++
sum = sum + counter
counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: So you are saying that it only really makes a difference when we are assigning the incremented variable to another variable?

Comment: I hope it is ok I copied this into my notes to help me remember.

Answer (score 3):

In your example it doesn't matter, since you do nothing with the value returned by `++counter`.

The only time it makes a difference is when you are using the value returned by the post/pre-increment operator.

For example, if you had a `return counter++;` or a `return ++counter;` statement, your method would return a different result based on which operator you used.

Comment: But let us assume we will be using the value returned by the method somewhere else.

Comment: @user1454994 it doesn't matter. Both `++counter` and `counter++` increment `counter`. Since your method returns `counter`, it doesn't matter which of the two operators you used.

Comment: just to clarify, if we assign the value of this method to another variable, such as in a driver class and we want to print the number of classes that are available, it won't make a difference? The variable will be assigned the value of counter?

Comment: @user1454994 if you mean something like `int count = something.howManyHandi();`, then yes, it doesn't matter whether you use `counter++` or `++counter` within `howManyHandi`. On the other hand, if anywhere in your code you have `int variable = counter++;` or `int variable = ++counter;`, the value of `variable` will be different based on which increment operator you use.