# StackOverflow Error in program and I cant find the reason

Tags: java, runtime-error

```
void recur(int i)
{
    if(i==n)
        return;
    String sub="";
    for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        sub=s.substring(i,j);
        if(isPalindrome(sub))
            System.out.println(sub);
    }
    recur(i++);
}
```

I am encountering a `StackOverflowError` at the

```
sub=s.substring(I,j);
```

statement.

```
s="geeks", initial value of I=0;
```

Comment: Where is your variable n instantiated? I think i==n returns false for all values of 'i' which is resulting in a StackOverflowError

Comment: What is `n` ? If `i` is never `n`, this will never stop and being a recursive function, it will generate a stack overflow.

Comment: Please format your question so we can easily read it.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `recur(++i)`, or `recur(i+1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use post increment and pre increment in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390737/when-to-use-post-increment-and-pre-increment-in-java)

Comment: this function does not compile, what is `n` between?

Answer (score 1):

```
recur(i++);
```

The value of the expression `i++` is the value of `i` at the current time; and afterwards you increment it.

As such, you are basically invoking:

```
recur(i);
i++;
```

And so you are just invoking `recur` again with the same parameter.

Try:

```
recur(++i);
```

Comment: this function does not compile, what is `n` between?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public class P {

    public static final String s="geeks";

    static void recur(int i){

        int n=6;   //Size of string

        if(i==n)
            return;

        String sub="";

        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            sub=s.substring(i,j);
            //Any Function
            System.out.println(sub);
        }
        recur(++i);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        P.recur(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: "`//Size of string`" isn't the size of the string 5? You wouldn't need the comment if you used `s.length()`.

Comment: Yes you can add `s.length()`, and change the iteration to  `for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++)`